# How to properly integrate JQuery with IP.Board?

Tags: jquery, css, url, background-image, ipb

I've been having some trouble integrating a JQuery background chooser with an IP.Board forum. I've tried including noConflict but it seems to disable JQuery completely. The code I'm using is this:

```
$("#Btn").click(function(){
    $("#Image").css("backgroundImage", "url('"+$("#ImageUrl").val()+"')");
});
```

Comment: Is there a console error? What is the value of `$("#ImageUrl").val()`?

Comment: @tb11, No error that I know of. The value of `$("#ImageUrl").val()` would be the URL of the image the background image should be set to.

Comment: Can you replicate the error in a jsfiddle? The code you have looks good to me.

Comment: @tb11, it works fine in a JSFiddle, as can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/mSAsU/. I think the problem lies with jQuery conflicting with IP.Board's prototype.js library but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery(elem)` instead of `$(elem)` or if you want to use `$` then do what I did:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // jQuery code goes here
});
```